# tar: don't create "." directory

Tags: tar

I'm creating a `.tar.xz` archive like this:

```bsh
XZ_DEFAULTS="T$(nproc)" tar cvfJ "$archive" -C "$dir" .
```

It's creating this useless `.` directory when I try to open the archive:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
(shopt -s dotglob && cd "$dir" && XZ_DEFAULTS="--threads=0" tar cvfJ "$archive" *)
```

(Improved with [Freddy's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592917/tar-dont-create-directory/592920?noredirect=1#comment1106028_592920))

It's a little annoying because `$archive` has to be an absolute path or relative to `$dir` now <del>and `*` doesn't generally include dot files</del>, but I can work around that at least.

Comment: Enable `dotglob` if you use `bash` and want to include hidden files:
`(shopt -s dotglob; cd "$dir"; XZ_DEFAULTS="T$(nproc)" tar cvfJ "$archive" *)`